# Counting elements from html source

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have a problem with counting elements in HTML below:

```
<div id="photos-view" class="all visible">
  <div class="sort-container">
      <h2 class="sort-title sort-zone">Zone1<span>3</span></h2>
    <section data-index="0" class="section-0">
      <div id="photo-holder-9C9E72AA-5A40-D1A1-BF44-CB5ED13EA628" class="photo-holder" data-id="9C9E72AA-5A40-D1A1-BF44-CB5ED13EA628" data-itemid="9C9E72AA-5A40-D1A1-BF44-CB5ED13EA628">
        <picture id="photo-9C9E72AA-5A40-D1A1-BF44-CB5ED13EA628">
          <img srcset="" src="data:image/jpeg;base64" data-sheet-id="32" data-itemid="9C9E72AA-5A40-D1A1-BF44-CB5ED13EA628" data-id="9C9E72AA-5A40-D1A1-BF44-CB5ED13EA628" data-index="0" data-group="0283">
        </picture>
      </div>
      <div id="photo-holder-667CBB46-6BC4-3BCE-69F6-DB79482204F6" class="photo-holder" data-id="667CBB46-6BC4-3BCE-69F6-DB79482204F6" data-itemid="667CBB46-6BC4-3BCE-69F6-DB79482204F6">
        <picture id="photo-667CBB46-6BC4-3BCE-69F6-DB79482204F6">
          <img srcset="" src="data:image/jpeg;base64" data-sheet-id="32" data-itemid="667CBB46-6BC4-3BCE-69F6-DB79482204F6" data-id="667CBB46-6BC4-3BCE-69F6-DB79482204F6" data-index="1" data-group="0283">
        </picture>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="sort-container">
      <h2 class="sort-title sort-zone">Zone2<span>1</span></h2>
    <section data-index="1" class="section-1">
      <div id="photo-holder-C1131DD2-B422-FE8E-2AF0-2581527CEA9E" class="photo-holder" data-id="C1131DD2-B422-FE8E-2AF0-2581527CEA9E" data-itemid="C1131DD2-B422-FE8E-2AF0-2581527CEA9E">
        <picture id="photo-C1131DD2-B422-FE8E-2AF0-2581527CEA9E">
          <img srcset="" src="data:image/jpeg;base64" data-sheet-id="34" data-itemid="C1131DD2-B422-FE8E-2AF0-2581527CEA9E" data-id="C1131DD2-B422-FE8E-2AF0-2581527CEA9E" data-index="0" data-group="2831">
        </picture>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see there are two classes named "sort-title sort-zone". I need to check in my test:

1. Is class="sort-title sort-zone" contains text "Zone1" and
   3
2. Is class="sort-title sort-zone" contains text "Zone2" and 1

Comment: What do you have so far and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: `problem with counting elements` which elements are you trying to count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply save WebElements in a list for class `sort-container` like this :

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.className("sort-container"));
```

and using :

```
list.get(0).getText();
list.get(1).getText();
```

can give you :

```
Zone13
Zone21
```

as output which you can use for assertions.

Answer (score 0):

I advice using JSoup to parse the document.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
List<String> L = doc.select('.sort-title.sort-zone').eachText​();

return L.size()==2 && L.get(0).equals("Zone13") && L.get(1).equals("Zone21");
```

This is a sample code addressing your issue. Feel free to improve it according to your needs.